how to configure the HTTP client in OpenAI
The way to use httpx to create a client:
with httpx.Client(headers=headers,params=params) as client:
    r = client.post(url, data=data)

However, I'd like to configure this into using openai package:
client = openai.OpenAI(api_key='...',
                        http_client=httpx.Client(headers=headers,params=params))

I'm not sure if I'm going to use either one:
client.chat.completions.create()

client.post()

